# Pythonic way to find datetime with smallest time difference to target from list?

Tags: python

I have a datetime object `target_time`. I also have a list such that `times_list[i]['time']` is a datetime object. I want to iterate through this list and find the index of the item that has the smallest time distance from `target_time`. These differences will be in the order of milliseconds, and the range of times covered in the list will be in the order of minutes. My current solution is rather clunky:

```
best_index = -1
best_diff = 999999999999.0
for i in range(len(times_List)):
    cur_time = times_list[i]['time']
    diff = abs((cur_time-target_time).total_seconds()))
    if diff < best_diff:
        best_index = i
        best_diff = diff
if best_index > -1:
    result = times_list[best_index]['time']
```

Is there a less clunky and more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Please give us sample data structures to work with, and the desired output for these samples of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import operator
deltas = [abs(ti['time'] - target_time) for ti in times_list]
min_index, min_delta = min(enumerate(deltas), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#min) to find the smallest difference. Combine that with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) to keep track of the indices:

```
min_pos, min_diff = min(enumerate(times_list), key=lambda t: abs(target_time - t[1]['time']))
```

No need to generate an intermediate list of differences.

Comment: pretty sure `t[1]` is an error here as `t[i]` is the loop variable.

Comment: @HalTL no, 1 is corect. It's the second item of the tuple passed to the lambda expression. There is no loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method:

```
temp = sorted(times_list, key=lambda x: abs(abs((x-target_time).total_seconds())))
result = times_list.index(temp[0])
```

Comment: I like that this doesn't require an import.

Comment: I'll never understand why one prefers lambda over a list comprehension.

Comment: This method is less efficient than others. The `sort()` is O(n log n) _plus_ the list needs to be rescanned to locate the item. Other solutions that use `min()` are O(n).

Answer (score 0):

A function to find the closest:

```
from datetime import datetime

def closest(target, dates):    
    return min(dates, key=lambda date: abs(date-target))


print(closest(target1, dates))
#2014-12-31 16:00:00

print(closest(target2, dates))
#2015-01-01 12:00:00
print(abs(target1 - target2))
```

Comment: OP also requires the index of the item with the smallest delta.